# JavaScript works in Firefox and Safari, but not in Internet Explorer or Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, safari

I manage a site for our training company. This site wants to embed an API from Indeed.com that displays a set of job opportunities from Indeed. From the Indeed site I got JavaScript code (jobroll - see [link](http://www.indeed.nl/jsp/create_jobroll.jsp)) and implemented that on a testpage.

This testpage can be found [here](http://www.mentorum.nl/vacatures.html). Because you can use different keywords, I want the result of four keywords shown in four columns, two columns per row. The JavaScript code works in Firefox and Safari, but not in Internet Explorer or Chrome. I am not a coder and therefore need your help. What am I doing wrong or what is missing?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is with a mime-type mismatch, as indicated in the console output of both Internet Explorer and Google Chrome - firefox appears to just let this slide. It probably shouldn't.

Consider the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="...indeed.nl/jobroll?q=tmap&l=&limit=10"></script>
```

This expects the *jobroll* resource to be a JavaScript resource (which is it, if you inspect the response body). But the problem is with indeed.nl sending JavaScript, while claiming it to be HTML. A quick inspection of the response headers will reveal this:

[image]

Note the response type of the resource is not `text/javascript`, but instead `text/html`. This is the security issue that Internet Explorer and Chrome are not letting slide.

In order to use this resource you'll need to get the providers of this data to adjust their response headers to identify this as script rather than markup. Alternatively, you could use a local resource that loads this content and returns it with the correct response headers to your front end code.